# MySQL 8 get PROCEDURE / FUNCTION full definition

Tags: mysql-8.0, mysql-function

I need to get the user defined **PROCEDURE / FUNCTION** full definition in **MySQL 8**.

**MySQL 5.6** contain **mysql.proc** table there we can get the function full definition but MySQL 8 does not contain the **proc** table.

But **MySQL 5.6** and **8** also have **information_schema.ROUTINES** table it contain only the function body,
I can not find functions `parameter` and `return` types.

what I did in MySQL 5.6

```
SELECT 
  `name` AS _schema, 
   CONVERT(body USING utf8) AS _schemaDef, 
   CONVERT(param_list USING utf8) AS param_list,
   CONVERT(`returns` USING utf8) AS `returns`
FROM mysql.proc 
WHERE db = 'my_db_name'
```

Any idea how to do this MySQL 8?

**My ultimate target is copying all function and procedure from one DB to another DB by using PHP**

I have find a solution that...

> SHOW CREATE FUNCTION function_name

Above query work fine in **MySQL 5.6** and **8**.
But first I have to get list of **FUNCTION** names from **information_schema.ROUTINES** table and loop the record set, Inside the loop I have to run the above **SHOW CREATE FUNCTION** query.

How to Optimize this flow?